# String sequential grouping in Oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g

My task is to group similar digits/characters in a given string,
For e.g.: 
The output of the SQL for the string `4455599` should be `44 555 99` and is working with following query:

```
with t(str)
as (
  select '4455599' from dual
)
select listagg(str_grouped ,' ') within group (order by rownum) str_split
from(
    select listagg ( str) within group ( order by lvl) str_grouped
    from(
        select level lvl, 
               substr(str,level,1) str, 
               dense_rank() over( order by substr(str,level,1)) drank_no
        from t
          connect by level <= length(str)
    )
 group by drank_no
  );
```

But the query fails with the following data as I am currently using `dense_rank`.

`445559944`, expected `44 555 99 44` but getting `4444 555 99`.

`bb119911`, expected `bb 11 99 11`  but getting `1111 99 bb`.

Help me on this, welcome all regular expression query.

Comment: The rule is not clear, what would be the output for `46455599464`? How would you group the `6`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Backreferences to the rescue:

```
select 
    regexp_replace('4455599', '((.)\2*)', '\1 ')
from dual;
```

Output:

```
44 555 99
```

**Explanation**

`((.)\2*)` defines two capturing groups where:

`(.)` matches any single character and captures it in group 2.

`\2*` is a backreference to the character captured in group 2, which matches the same character zero or more times.

`((.)\2*)` therefore matches a sequence of one-or-more of the same character and captures the sequence in group 1.

`\1`  replaces the characters matched with the contents of group 1, followed by a space.

Backreferences are counted from left-to-right starting with 1 (group 0 is the entire match). So if you have the pattern `(((a)b)c)d` the innermost `(a)` is group 3, `((a)b)` is group 2, `(((a)b)c)` is group 1, and if you're using a normal regex engine (not oracle's), the entire pattern `(((a)b)c)d` is captured in group 0.

**Test cases**

```
select 
    val, regexp_replace(val, '((.)\2*)', '\1 ') as result
from (
    select '445559944' as val from dual
    union all select 'bb119911' as val from dual
    union all select '46455599464' as val from dual
) foo;
```

Output:

```
VAL         RESULT
----------- ------------------
445559944   44 555 99 44 
bb119911    bb 11 99 11 
46455599464 4 6 4 555 99 4 6 4
```

Comment: nice solution +1. Could you please explain the pattern `((.)\2*)`

Comment: @LalitKumarB Explanation added.